# search value in column with separation ","

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I use in a userform, which is that I search for a value that I type in txtreg (textBox) that is in column A or D. and the results to be displayed in a listbox called (txtledglist).
The result is in column B, when displayed in txtledglist (ListBox) it is concatenated with the corresponding value in same row in column C.

Now the values in A is normal (1 value) but in D the values that I am searching for some of them will be separated by ",".

So with my code below it searches perfectly when only 1 value is there in A or D as well, but when there is "," between values it does not find anything. how can I add that it searches as well in values between each "," in the column D?

I hope that I have explained my idea... thanks everyone

my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub txtreg_Change()

    Dim lookupValue As String: lookupValue = txtreg.value
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("L 403")
    
    txtledglist.Clear
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A:A,D:D")  ' Update the range to include columns A and D
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim firstCell As Range: Set firstCell = rng.Find(What:=lookupValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not firstCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim cell As Range: Set cell = firstCell
        Dim results() As Variant
        Dim count As Long: count = 0
        
        Do
            count = count + 1
            Set cell = rng.FindNext(cell)
        Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Address <> firstCell.Address
        
        ReDim results(1 To count, 1 To 1)
        
        Set cell = rng.Find(What:=lookupValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        Dim index As Long: index = 1
        Do
            results(index, 1) = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "B").value & "  " & ws.Cells(cell.Row, "C").value
            index = index + 1
            Set cell = rng.FindNext(cell)
        Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Address <> firstCell.Address
        
        txtledglist.List = results
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are sure that the values you search cannot contain each other (e.g. because they have a fix length, e.g. each of them is 8 characters long), then you can replace `LookAt:=xlWhole` with `LookAt:=xlPart`. However, if that's not the case and you search for id "ABC123", it will find "ABC1230" and "ABC1234" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the values in column D and check if any of the individual values match.

```
Private Sub txtreg_Change()

    Dim lookupValue As String: lookupValue = txtreg.value
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("L 403")
    
    txtledglist.Clear
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A:A,D:D")  ' Update the range to include columns A and D
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim firstCell As Range: Set firstCell = rng.Find(What:=lookupValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not firstCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim cell As Range: Set cell = firstCell
        Dim results() As Variant
        Dim count As Long: count = 0
        
        Do
            count = count + 1
            Set cell = rng.FindNext(cell)
        Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Address <> firstCell.Address
        
        ReDim results(1 To count, 1 To 1)
        
        Set cell = rng.Find(What:=lookupValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        Dim index As Long: index = 1
        Do
            Dim values() As String
            values = Split(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value, ",") ' Split the values in column D by comma
            
            ' Iterate through each split value and check if it matches the lookupValue
            For Each value In values
                If Trim(value) = lookupValue Then
                    results(index, 1) = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "B").value & "  " & ws.Cells(cell.Row, "C").value
                    index = index + 1
                    Exit For ' Exit the loop if a match is found
                End If
            Next value
            
            Set cell = rng.FindNext(cell)
        Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Address <> firstCell.Address

        txtledglist.List = results

    End If
End Sub
```